# c++ How to do compile-time branching on a function that is templated with an integer (and how to limit the number of valid values)?

Tags: templates

if I have a templated function that is templated using an int, how can I do compile-time branching on the value of this integer? for example (I know this is not a good use of templates - it's just a simple example to illustrate what I mean):

```
template<int Dimension>
std::string get_name() {
    // if Dimension == 1 return "line";
    // else if Dimension == 2 return "area";
    // else if Dimension == 3 return "volume";
    // else return std::std::to_string(Dimension) + "D construct";
}
```

How can I implement this branching?

and second question: How can I restrict the valid values of Dimension to say 1-100 ?

Comment: please use a real example. compile-time branching in presence of `std::string` looks pointless. what would you need it for? `std::string`is more or less unusable as a constant expression. but in practice, it would inline to something short anyway,

Comment: oh, and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If

Answer (score 2):

You can use template specialization for the branch:

```
template<int Dimension>
std::string get_name() {
    return std::to_string(Dimension) + "D construct";
}
template<>
std::string get_name<1>() {
    return "line";
}
```

And SFINAE in order to limit the dimensions:

```
template<int Dimension>
std::enable_if_t<Dimension <= 100 , std::string> get_name() {
    return std::to_string(Dimension) + "D construct";
}
template<>
std::string get_name<1>() {
    return "line";
}
```